# Creating multiples of children in Json

Tags: arrays, json

Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to json so need a bit of help 
When i first got our database in it worked fine  like so

```
{    
   "Audi":[
      "80",
      "100",
   ],
   "Bentley":[
      "Azure",
      "(C)",
   ]
}
```

Now we want to extend it a bit more so it is more like the below but it obviously is wrong?

```
    { "Audi": [
    “50”:[
    “50 L(1974-1978)”:["Alternators","Starter Motors"]],
    “50 GL(1974-1978)”:["Alternators","Starter Motors"]],
    “A1”:[
    “A1 1.2 TFSI(2010-)”:["Alternators","Starter Motors"]],
    “A1 1.4 TFSI(2010-)”:["Alternators","Starter Motors"]],
    }
```

so the hierarchy is more like= make/ model / "model engine and year" / then product categories. Hope this make sense

Comment: As you can see in your first example, `"key":value` pairs have to go inside `{ ... }` and `lists, of, values` inside `[ ... ]`. Then there is http://json.org/, which has nice syntax diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You were close

```
{
    "Audi": {
        "50": { "50 L(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"],
                "50GL(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"] },
        "A1": { "A11.2TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"],
                "A11.4TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill be honest I did try your version above before commenting but this error occured? So I guess not?https://www.evernote.com/shard/s334/sh/6a696030-1f0d-4441-8524-ece51b2ec39c/19dcad7cc97848e09073b7a4ca9dcbf8    Parse error on line 3:
...udi": [        "50": [            "50 
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone I've worked it out and it works fine now. I used a really helpful editor and validator which can be found here.. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
Below is the version which worked.

```
{
    "Audi":{
    "50": {
        "50 L(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"], 
        "50GL(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"] }, 
        "A1": {
        "A1 1.2TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"], 
        "A1 1.4TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"], 
        "A1 Sportback 1.6 TDI(2010-)":["Alternators","Starter Motors"], 
        "A1 Sportback 2.0 TDI(2011-)":["Alternators","Starter Motors"] }
        },
 "Audiv2":{
    "50": {
        "50 L(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"], 
        "50GL(1974-1978)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"] }, 
    "A1": {
        "A1 1.2TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"], 
        "A1 1.4TFSI(2010-)": ["Alternators", "Starter Motors"],  
        "A1 Sportback 2.0 TDI(2011-)":["Alternators","Starter Motors"] }}

}
```